# C# Winforms and command line batch files

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file

I have this running from my c# winforms app:

```
string ExecutableFilePath = @"Scripts.bat";
string Arguments = @"";

if (File.Exists(ExecutableFilePath )) {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ExecutableFilePath , Arguments);
}
```

When that runs I get to see the cmd window until it finishes.

Is there a way to get that to run without showing it to the user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class and set the following properties

```
  string ExecutableFilePath = @"Scripts.bat";
  string Arguments = @"";

  if (File.Exists(ExecutableFilePath ))
  {
       ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(ExecutableFilePath , Arguments);
       psi.UseShellExecute = false;
       psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
       Process.Start(psi);
  }
```

Comment: Ok ok, I won't cheat again - will delete my response and upvote you :)

Comment: @MattRoberts actually I removed my downvote, but for future - that's unfair just write anything to make your answer appear first :)

Comment: That works just fine. Thanks. One last thing, is there a way to get when/if the process has finished executing?

Comment: `Process.WaitForExit()` will block the current thread until the process exits.

Comment: Not getting that under the Process intellisense

Comment: Got it. Needed to make new process first then call p.WaitForExit(). Thanks